# Extern inside function

Tags: c

I know this is an basic question , not sure the c standard allows it to do or not .I was given a code snippet in an interview and was asked to give the output.

I have declared an extern and an local variable with the same name inside a function it throws a re declaration error ( just like global) what could be the reason ? since i is declared in the same block, extern should be able to find it rite ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){


int i = 10;
extern int i ;


printf("%d \n",i);

}

Error : 1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:13: error: extern declaration of ‘i’ follows declaration with no linkage
1.c:12: note: previous definition of ‘i’ was here
```

Comment: @KeineLust it works for global why not local ? I had thought all these days that extern should be able to find variable in the same or the other files

Comment: @KeineLust That is not what extern means. It can very well find a declaration in the current unit.

Comment: Why would you even *want* to do this?

Comment: @2501, you are right, sorry, I mean not in the current block ...

Comment: @toby turned out to be an interview question .

Comment: @SantoshPai Then the short answer is no, the C standard does not allow this

Comment: @Toby thanks somehow i couldnt say this and lost my chances to get the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 10;
extern int i ;
```

The first, because it is function scope, means "declare and define a variable `i` which is local to the function". The variable shall have no linkage because it is function local; specifically (C11 6.2.2 paragraph 6):

> The following identifiers have no linkage: [ ... ]; a block scope identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.

The second statement on the other hand says "declare a variable `i` which has external linkage".

It is allowed, within certain limitations, to re-declare a variable, but in general the declarations must be consistent; the two statements above contradict. Furthermore, an identifier with no linkage cannot be re-declared - from C11 6.7 paragraph 3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one
>   declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with
>   the same scope and in the same name space

(after which some exceptions are listed, but they are not relevant here).

If the statements were *outside* the function (at file scope level) then the `int i = 10;` declaration would indicate external linkage, so the following declaration is consistent - and in fact, it doesn't even need to be consistent, since 6.2.2 paragraph 4 applies:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, <sup>31)</sup> if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
>   declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

(So, it is perfectly legal at file scope to declare `static int i = 0; extern int i;` - even though the declarations are inconsistent, the second is allowed by the above rule, though I don't know the rationale for this. You cannot however have those statements in the opposite order).

Comment: Now its clear ,thanks for the detailed answer @davmac

Comment: Thumbs up for the static example @davmac

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare two variables with the same name in the same block, and that's what you are trying. And the compiler is telling you that. What could be the reason for the error? The C language says so it's not allowed, and the compiler implements the C language.

The compiler found the first "i" in the block just fine, that's why it complained.

What would you expect if this was accepted and you used i in the block? How is the compiler to know which of two i's you mean?

Comment: But if we declare int i as global and followed by extern then it compiles ok .Why ?

Comment: @SanthoshPai It doesn't, if you do it in the same block.

Comment: @SanthoshPai because a global definition has external linkage by default, so the following declaration is consistent with it. Inside the function, the definition has no linkage, so the `extern` declaration is inconsistent. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick test to same problem. Three ways to use extern. Not to beauty contest but got toy program just working. Using: g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic test1.cpp test2.cpp test3.cpp -o test. There is room for improvement.

```
//to save space: ifndefs and std libs removed...!
k.h:
extern int k; //declaration...
-----------------------------------------
test1.h:
#include "k.h"...
-----------------------------------------
test1.cpp:
#include "test1.h"
#include "test2.h"
#include "test3.h"...
-----------------------------------------
using namespace std;
int var = 10;       //defined here
int k = 1000;       //declared in k.h, defined here
int main(){
    extern int var2;//declaration here
    k = 200;//declared k.h, defined value 1000 at test1, change value here
    mytest2();  //test2
    std::cout << "at test1 var2:"<< var2 << endl;
    cout << "Let us see out:" << endl;
    out();      //test2
    cout << "Let us see check:" << endl;
    check();    //test3
}
------------------------------------------
test2.h:...
#include "k.h"
void mytest2();
void out();...
-------------------------------------------
test2.cpp:
#include "test2.h"

using namespace std;
int var2 = 11111;   //declared in test1, defined here
extern int var;     //declared here, defined in test1
void mytest2(){
    cout << "at test2 var2: " << var2 << endl;
    var2 *= 2;      //change value here
}
void out(){
    cout << "at test2 var " << var << endl;
    cout << "at test2 k " << k << endl;
}
-------------------------------------------
test3.h:...
#include "k.h"
void check(void);...
-------------------------------------------
test3.cpp:
#include "test3.h"
using namespace std;
extern int var;     //declared here, 
extern int var2;    //declared here

void check(){
    cout << "at test3 now var: " << var << endl;
    cout << "at test3 now var2: " << var2 << endl;
    cout << "at test3 now k: " << k << endl;
}
```